# Why CSS Pseudo Element not Working in Image

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

first I have tried to find answers on the stack overflow with a similar question but the results are still the same it doesn't show the image I mean.

so this is my html structure:

```
<div class="header__shape">
            <img src="img/rose.png" alt="rose couples" class="header__shape-img">
            <p class="header__shape-quote">
                Being someone’s first love may be great, <br>
                but to be their last is beyond perfect.
            </p>
</div>
```

and this is for my css along with the pseudo ::before

```
&-quote{
            position   : absolute;
            font-size  : $font-size-2;
            font-family: $font-secondary;
            color      : $color-font;
            line-height: 1.3;
            right      : 45rem;
            top        : 45rem;

            &::before{
                content         : "";
                background-image: url(../../img/quote.png);
                height          : 50px;
                display         : block;
                width           : 50px;

            }
        }
```

what i want like this [image] but in reality nothing happen [image]

Comment: make sure the url image is correct and i suggest you add "" to url, your code works correctly, check this: https://codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/zYqjOvd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would solve it. First you need to give the parent a `position: relative` in order to move the `p` tag around in the `div`

And then give the pseudo-element position absolute to move it around the `p` tag.

```
.header__shape {
    position: relative;
}

.header__shape-quote {
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30rem;
    top: 40rem;

}

.header__shape-quote::before {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: -60px;
    /* must have for fontawesome */
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f10e";
}
```

[image]

and in a different way. And I personally recommend this one. Over the absolute in the above example. But I don't know which is better for you. So I added both

```css
.header__shape {
  position: relative;
}

.header__shape-quote {
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: red;
  margin-left: 5rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.header__shape-quote::before {
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -60px;
  /* must have for fontawesome */
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f10e";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="header__shape">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600" rose couples class="header__shape-img">
  <p class="header__shape-quote">
    Being someone’s first love may be great, <br> but to be their last is beyond perfect.
  </p>
</div>
```

[image]

### Edit

To use your assets is just normal. Just add the path in the `URL` and give it `height` and `width` and you should be good to go.

```css
.header__shape {
  position: relative;
}

.header__shape-quote {
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: red;
  margin-left: 5rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.header__shape-quote::before {
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -60px;
  /* must have for fontawesome */
  display: inline-block;
  /* content: url('../images/caret-down-solid.svg'); */
  content: url("https://picsum.photos/40");
}
```

```html
<div class="header__shape">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600" rose couples class="header__shape-img">
  <p class="header__shape-quote">
    Being someone’s first love may be great, <br> but to be their last is beyond perfect.
  </p>
</div>
```

[image]

You can also add it as a `background-image` instead of adding the `URL` in the `content`. that's totally fine.

```css
.header__shape {
  position: relative;
}

.header__shape-quote {
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: red;
  margin-left: 5rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.header__shape-quote::before {
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -60px;
  /* must have for fontawesome */
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  /*  background: url('../images/caret-down-solid.svg') no-repeat;  that works fine i'm just using external link  */
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/40') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__shape">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600" rose couples class="header__shape-img">
  <p class="header__shape-quote">
    Being someone’s first love may be great, <br> but to be their last is beyond perfect.
  </p>
</div>
```

### Feel free to pick the way that suits you the most.

That doesn't help? please let me know. and I will try my best to help out.

Comment: first answer why use icon? whereas I want it to immediately use the assets I have,

then for the second answer, I have used this alternative method which is a question for me. which one is better? use 1 element with pseudo element for image .. or use 2 element where other element is image?

i am confused for the best practice to implement this case .. thanks

Comment: I prefer to use font awesome it is easy to handle ( Since its only a font ). Also, try to add your assets does it work? or not. And am sorry I'm not sure which way is more efficient.  I just use this way because I think it's better.

Comment: how to use assets cannot yet, because this is what I asked. I am looking for this answer because in the future I will use the same method for different designs

Comment: finally.. thank you ahmad.. I've got what I want from you.. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try by adding `<q>` tag so if you want to add CSS for `<q>` tag, you can add your CSS class

```
<div class="header__shape">
            <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="rose couples" class="header__shape-img">
            <p><q>
                Being someone’s first love may be great, <br>
                but to be their last is beyond perfect.</q>
            </p>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like this is not the answer I want, which I want to use pseudo elements because I use this for my project

Answer (score 0):

Add float, background-size properties to the pseudo-element's styles as below:

```
&-quote {
        position   : absolute;
        font-size  : $font-size-2;
        font-family: $font-secondary;
        color      : $color-font;
        line-height: 1.3;
        right      : 45rem;
        top        : 45rem;

        &::before {
            content         : "";
            background-image: url(../../img/quote.png);                
            height          : 50px;
            width           : 50px;
            /* new properties */
            float: left;
            background-size: contain;
        }
}
```